# angular directive DOM manipulation behavior link

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive which the link function appears to be executing directly, but the DOM remains unchanged.

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) {
        console.log($element[0]);
        $($element[0]).addClass('animateMe');
    });

}
```

The element that is logged to the console has the added class; however the element in the DOM does not. What would be causing this behavior?

Comment: Can you add a plunker?

Comment: First, `$element.addClass('animateMe')` should suffice. Second, you're only adding the class in the `$routeChangeStart` event handler. Does the element even exist on the page for you to see it?

Comment: Assuming your browser highlights elements in the page when you hover over them in the console, does the element highlight in the page when you hover over the logged one? I feel you're probably seeing a different element in the page

Comment: It seems to be something with applying it to the custom directive element directly. When applied to the content inside it works fine.